# Android SurfaceView current thread reference

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm following this tutorial on game development, and I've ran across something that is a little bit puzzling to me.

So in the tutorial, a class that extends SurfaceView implementing Runnable is created for managing the main game content view. The surface view is set as the content view of the main activity as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GameView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameView = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        gameView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gameView.resume();
    }
}
```

The SurfaceView class is defined as following:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    Thread gameThread = null;
    private boolean playing;

    public TDView(Context context) {
        super(context);

       // other game logic
    }

    public void pause() {
        playing = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        playing = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (playing) {
            update();
            draw();
            control();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't get me wrong - the code works perfectly, but I am confused as to **where does the gameThread variable get instantiated?** There is no line of code anywhere in my project indicating it does, besides in the resume method. **Is the resume method called on creation of the GameView instance, or is there something else I am missing?**

Excuse me if this is a silly question, but I couldn't figure out even how to google this.

Comment: At `gameThread = new Thread(this);` the Runnable implementation passed to the Thread's constructor and `gameThread.start()` executes the Overwritten `run()` method. See [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: But that code is in the resume() method of GameView. Is that method called on creation of the GameView instance?

Comment: It is called when the game view is resumed; this should be after the view is displayed and "active", so that way the game `Thread` instance isn't trying to manipulate the `SurfaceView` when it's not valid for rendering.  Without seeing the remaining code, it probably happens during activity lifecycle (e.g. `Activity.onResume`) and/or a menu item to start/pause/resume game.

Comment: You are right it happens during activity lifecycle (onResume and onPause), I've added those bits of code to the original post. But I still don't understand entirely though - if the resume method has never been called (assuming the GameView has just been instantiated and then put into the background), how can the pause method pause the gameThread which is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pause()` won't be called if Activity is not resumed. So this approach is fine. Everytime `pause()` is called gameThread is not null.

Comment: I see I should have been looking into the activity lifecycle. Thanks!